# Making a repeating iterator over a range of digits?

Tags: python, iterator, modulo

I'm trying to make an iterator that prints the repeating sequence

```
0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, ...
```

I want an iterator so I can use .next(), and I want it to loop around to 0 when .next() is called while the iterator is at 9.
But the thing is that I'll probably have a lot of these, so I don't just want to do `itertools.cycle([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])`.

I don't want to have that many repeated lists of the same sequence in memory. I'd rather have the function x + 1 % 10 in each of the iterators and just have the iterator increment x every time next is called. I can't seem to figure out how to do this though with itertools. Is there a pythonic way of doing this?

Comment: I don't understand why you don't want to use `itertools.cycle`...

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga Its not that I don't want to use it, I just dont want to use it with the list [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]) As I said I'll probably have a lot of these iterators, and I don't want each iterator to have its own copy of the same list of digits since that seems really wasteful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write an generator that uses `range`

```
def my_cycle(start, stop, step=1):
    while True:
        for x in range(start, stop, step):
            yield x

c = my_cycle(0, 10)
```

Comment: I believe the implementation of `cycle` effectively materializes the iterable and keeps it around, at least, that is implied by the sample implementation in the [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.cycle) and the warning about auxiliary storage.

Comment: Actually it is exactly that warning that made me ask this question instead of going with cycle

Answer (score 2):

You can use your own custom generator:

```
def cycle_range(xr):
    while True:
        for x in xr:
            yield x
```

Assuming you are on Python 2, use:

```
r = xrange(9)
it1 = cycle_range(xr)
it2 = cycle_range(xr)
```

For memory efficiency.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a custom generator like this:

```
def single_digit_ints():
    i = 0
    while True:
        yield i
        i = (i + 1) % 10

for i in single_digit_ints():
    # ...
```

Answer (score 1):

This is one way via `itertools`:

```
import itertools

def counter():
    for i in itertools.count(1):
        yield i%10

g = counter()
```